# Minimum of i.i.d. Random Variables

Tags: distributions, random-variable, order-statistics, iid

What importance does the minimum of an identical and independently distributed random variables play in probability distribution?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you are interested in?

Comment: Okay this is it, I'm working on this project and the topic is the distribution of the minimum of several iid exponential random variables but is been difficult to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Please take the time to edit your question and be specific about what you are interested in. The distribution of the minimum of iid exponentials is quite a different thing than the importance of the minimum of (general) iid variables. Please indicate what exactly about the minimum you are interested in - its expectation, or the full distribution, etc.

Comment: Or are you asking for examples for what this minimum is used for in statistical applications?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/how-to-calculate-the-distribution-of-the-minimum-of-multiple-exponential-variabl